# Guide on how to solve Rush Hour Puzzle in Java obtaining lowest number of moves using A* . Need help on how to start and steps to follow

Tags: java, graph, a-star

Firstly, I have read every thread that I could find on stackoverflow or other internet searching. I did learn about different aspects, but it isn't exactly what I need.

I need to solve a Rush Hour puzzle of size no larger than 8 X 8 tiles.

As I have stated in title I want to use A*, as a heuristic for it I was going to use :
number of cars blocking the red car's ( the one that needs to be taken out ) path should decrease or stay the same.

I have read the BFS solution for Rush hour.

I don't know how to start or better said, what steps to follow.

In case anyone needs any explanation, here is the link to the task :

http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall04/cos402/assignments/rushhour/index.html

So far from what have I read ( especially from polygenelubricants's answer ) I need to generate a graph of stages including initial one and "succes" one  and determine the minimum path from initial to final using A* algorithm ?

Should I create a backtracking function to generate all the possible ( valid ) moves ?

As I have previously stated, I need help on outlining the steps I need to take rather than having issues with the implementation.

Edit : Do I need to generate all the possible moves  so I convert them into graph nodes, isn't that time consuming ? I need to solve a 8X8 puzzle in less than 10 seconds

Comment: You are doing this for homework?

Comment: Yes, I have no connection with princeton tho. Why ?

Comment: Homework questions to have the homework tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A* is an algorithm for searching [graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29).  Graphs consist of [nodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_%28graph_theory%29) and edges.  So we need to represent your problem as a graph.

We can call each possible state of the puzzle a node.  Two nodes have an edge between them if they can be reached from each other using exactly one move.

Now we need a start node and an end node.  **Which puzzle-states would represent our start- and end-nodes?**

Finally, A* requires one more thing:  an [admissable distance heuristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic) - a guess at how many moves the puzzle will take to complete.  The only restriction for this guess is that it *must* be less than the actual number of moves, so actually what we're looking for is a minimum-bound.  Setting the heuristic to 0 would satisfy this, but if we can come up with a better minimum-bound, the algorithm will run faster.  **Can you come up with a minimum-bound on the number of moves the puzzle will take to complete?**

Comment: The start node would represent the initial phase, and the end-node will be considered the phase when we managed to get the red car out.By  " coming up with a minimum-bound " you mean providing a function to guide the search better ? If so, a function that checks the manhatten distance to the exit will do ? Or one that counts how many cars are currently blocking the path ?

Comment: @pAndrei:  Yes on the first part, and to the second part:  both, sort of.  Remember, we're looking for a *minimum bound* on the number of moves, so it depends on what you consider "one move" (is moving one car three spaces at once considered one move or three?).  Assuming each space counts as one move, you *could* take the distance of the red car from the exit, but an even better bound would be that red-car distance PLUS the minimum distance needed to move the other cars out of our way!

Comment: Your answer was very useful to me, thank you ! Right now, I only have one question left. Should I generate all the stages ? Wouldn't that be really time consuming ? Should I use a classical backtracking or an optimized one ?  For an 8X8 Tiles puzzle I need to solve it in less than 10 seconds.

Comment: @pAndrei: I would use backtracking, though I don't know what you mean by "classical or optimized"